# Divide array integer 2 even sums

Tags: c++, arrays, integer

I am finding hard to solve this programming problem. I am required to take an array of integers that can be of size `N`, anywhere from `2 <= N <= 30`. I need to divide the array into two smaller arrays whose sums are equal, and if they are not equal, they need to be as close as possible to the same value. I would guess that using some sort of recursive function would be ideal in this situation, but if not, a dynamically programmed solution would work just as well.

Comment: check out balanced partition problem

Comment: you would become really famous if you can solve this problem in a polynomial time..

Comment: Dynamic programming is not an alternative solution to recursion. Rather, sometimes you can speed recursion up by avoiding recomputing some things over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can review [wikipedia article on Partition problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem). It provides a pseudocode of pseudopolynomial algorithm in c# which you can rather easily convert into c++:

```
public static bool BalancePartition(int[] S)
{
    int n = S.Length;
    int N = S.Sum();
    bool[,] P = new bool[N / 2 + 1, n + 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
        P[0, i] = true;

    for (int i = 1; i <= N / 2; i++)
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
            if (S[j - 1] <= i)
                P[i, j] = P[i, j - 1] || P[i - S[j - 1], j - 1];
            else
                P[i, j] = P[i, j - 1];

    return P[N / 2, n];
}
```